# Schroder numbers recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The Schröder number S_n is the number of lattice paths in the Cartesian plane that start at (0, 0), end at (n,n), contain no points above the line y=x, and are composed only of steps (0,1), (1, 0), and (1, 1).They are given by the recurrence relation.

[image]

I have googled alot but found no proof of the recurrence relation. Please provide a proof for the recurrence relation.Below is a detailed description.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchroederNumber.html

Comment: [This article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1319516616300184) seems relevant.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the recurrence for the Catalan numbers?

Comment: Can you provide a link or explanation for the proof of the generating function.

Comment: Yes I know the recurrence relation for catalan numbers but i am finding it difficult to enumerate schroder numbers

Comment: If you know the **proof** for the Catalan numbers recurrence, then the proof for Schroeder numbers is a simple adaptation...

Comment: You asked this same question 3 days ago at [Schroder numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782493/schroder-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

With a quick search on Wikipedia, I've found out that the $$G(x)=\frac{1-x-\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}{2x}= \Sigma S_nx^n$$ is a generating function for the Schroder numbers, $S_n$.

Now, we can simplify this by cross multiplying out, taking all the terms to the same side, and equating the coefficients of the resulting power series to $0$. This must be the source of the recurrence relation, though I have not verified it.

Comment: What is the proof for the generating function??

Comment: I believe the proof can be found in this book here.(https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Introductory_Combinatorics.html?id=XwvELp2LQ7oC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). I believe an online copy of the book is also available

Comment: Thank you it seems much clearer now.